# get the href attribute from the webpage?

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

I need the get the href attribute from the following:

```
<tr>
    <td><h2 class="officers"><a href="/finance/stocks/officerProfile?symbol=ABB.N&officerId=232795" class="link">Roger&nbsp;Agnelli</a></h2></td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>2002</td>
    <td>Non-Executive Member of the Board of Directors</td>
</tr>
```

what I am trying here is

```
$a = $tr->getElementsByTagName('a');

echo $a->getAttribute('href');
```

unable to get the href value.where i am missing?? what i need here i want the href link to be output and after that parse that href link to the 'officer id'.

Hope I am clear with my question.. Help me..

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) is not a method of [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) it's method of: [`DOMElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php). So you have to do following:

```
foreach ($a as $element){
    var_dump($element->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

instead of `echo $a->getAttribute('href');`.